# get a set of values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

i have a set of arrays:

```
$nums = array(2,3,1); 
$data = array(11,22,33,44,55,66);
```

what i want to do is to get a set of $data array from each number of `$nums` array,

the output must be:

```
output:
2=11,22
3=33,44,55
1=66
```

what i tried so far is to slice the array and remove the sliced values from an array but i didn't get the correct output.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($nums); $i++) { 
    $a = array_slice($data,0,$nums[$i]);
    for ($x=0; $x < $nums[$i]; $x++) { 
        unset($data[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `array_shift` to remove the first element.

```
$nums = array(2,3,1); 
$data = array(11,22,33,44,55,66);

foreach( $nums as $num ){
    $t = array();
    for ( $x = $num; $x>0; $x-- ) $t[] = array_shift($data);

    echo $num . " = " . implode(",",$t) . "<br />";
}
```

This will result to:

```
2 = 11,22
3 = 33,44,55
1 = 66
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use another flavor [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), it basically takes the array based on the offset that you inputted. It already takes care of the unsetting part since it already removes the portion that you selected.

```
$out = array();
foreach ($nums as $n) {
    $remove = array_splice($data, 0, $n);
    $out[] = $remove;
    echo $n . '=' . implode(',', $remove), "\n";
}
// since nums has 2, 3, 1, what it does is, each iteration, take 2, take 3, take 1
```

[Sample Output](https://3v4l.org/uUQVm)

Also you could do an alternative and have no function usage at all. You'd need another loop though, just save / record the last index so that you know where to start the next num extraction:

```
$last = 0; // recorder
$cnt = count($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nums); $i++) {
    $n = $nums[$i];
    echo $n . '=';
    for ($h = 0; $h < $n; $h++) {
        echo $data[$last] . ', ';
        $last++;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: @nikko `array_splice()` is the best/most direct call for your task.  This should be the approach that you implement.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7731a3cee43ba35950f62a2b2297b7ffbc1cc692  Using `array_shift()` requires iterated function calls, so it is less direct.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest and the simplest way,

```
<?php

$nums = array(2,3,1); 
$data = array(11,22,33,44,55,66);
$startingPoint = 0;
echo "output:"."\n";
foreach($nums as $num){
  $sliced_array = array_slice($data, $startingPoint, $num);
  $startingPoint = $num;
  echo $num."=".implode(",", $sliced_array)."\n";
}
?>
```